# Window.location is not navigating to the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in which after clicking login it should display home page but its not navigating when i use window.location since i what to display home page on same tab.

Below is the form (code)

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<p><input type="text" required value="Username"name="u"></p>
<p><input type="password" required value="Password" name="p"></p>

<p><input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Please help

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"> use this instead of submit

Comment: Where is the code which is supposed to navigate to the homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use button type ,instead of submit type
that is

```
<p><input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"></p>
```

if you still want to use submit type then you need to stop the submit event so do the following with submit type.

```
<p><input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form);return false" value="Login"></p>
```

thank you